# No option of installing Subgraph OS from USB Stick

Tags: usb, system-installation

I would like to install Subgraph OS. When I insert the USB Stick with Subgraph OS and press on "Install" or "Graphic Install", the installer doesn't allow me to install the OS from the USB Stick, only from a CD-ROM. There's no option whatssoever of installing it from the USB Stick, for some reason.

Help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An option of coverting the USB Stick to a USB Installer exists: 
https://subgraph.com/sgos-handbook/sgos_handbook.shtml#creating-a-usb-installer-using-gnome-disks

Look for Section number 3.3 - Installing from a USB drive on a Linux computer.